# process with comma separated json result

Tags: php, json

This is my query:

```
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
    $city= $details->city;
```

give result:

```
{
    "ip": "210.56.147.31",
    "hostname": "No Hostname",
    "city": null,
    "region": null,
    "country": "IN",
    "loc": "20.0000,77.0000",
    "org": "AS45774 Chandra Net Pvt. Limited, India"
}
```

I can get loc by :      `$loc= $details->loc;`

Which gives result: `loc is : 20.0000,77.0000` for `echo "loc is : $loc"`

I want to get longitude and lattitude separately in `$long` and `$latt`. how could be done? how both values can be fetched separated?

```
$loc= $details->loc[0]; //this is not correct
```

Comment: How do you normally split strings based on a character?

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the value using `explode()`. you can find details [here](https://www.php.net/explode)

```
$loc = $details->loc;
$latLong = explode(",",$loc);
$longitude = $latLong[0];
$lattitude = $latLong[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just explode the value on the `,`.

**Example**

```
$long = explode(',', $loc)[0];
$lat = explode(',', $loc)[1];
```

Note this will only work for later versions of PHP. If you're using an old version of PHP, you'll need to assign the array to a variable before referring to it's elements, like so:

```
$location = explode(',',$loc);

$lat = $location[0];
$long = $location[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` to split the string, and `list` to assign the two variables at the same time:

```
list($lat, $lon) = explode(",", $loc);
```